# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Modelo.Cliente.setNumeroIdentificacion(int)" because "this.c" is null

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I'm using stored procedures to find a person ID, but when looking for the person it indicates that it is null, I don't understand why it indicates that the value is null, in this line of code cs.setInt (1, identificationNumber); already has a value

```
    public Cliente buscarCliente(int numeroIdentificacion) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    // Instancia de la clase Cliente
    Cliente c = null;

    // Declaracion de variables
    Connection con = Conectar();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    int resultado = 0;
    
    try {
        
        cs = con.prepareCall("{call dbo.SPBuscarCliente(?)}");
        cs.setInt(1, numeroIdentificacion);
        resultado = cs.executeUpdate();
        rs = cs.executeQuery();
        
        while(rs.next()){
            c = new Cliente();
            c.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            c.setNumeroIdentificacion(rs.getInt(2));
            c.setNombre(rs.getString(3));
            c.setPrimerApellido(rs.getString(4));
            c.setSegundoApellido(rs.getString(5));
            c.setDireccion(rs.getString(6));
            c.setEstado(rs.getString(7));
            
        }
        
    } catch (SQLException e){
       
        System.err.println(e);
        
    }
    
    return c;
}
```

This my store procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPBuscarCliente]
-- Declaracion de variables
(@NumeroIdentificacion AS INT)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM Cliente WHERE NumeroIdentificacion = @NumeroIdentificacion

END
```

Comment: Some sql servers do not use the { ... } when called from java. Try to remove the braces.

Comment: Why you are working with stored procedure and not directly with sql?

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace